# Difference between sizeof(struct name_of_struct) vs sizeof(name_of_struct)?

Tags: c++

What are the differences between:

```
sizeof(struct name_of_struct)
```

vs

```
sizeof(name_of_struct)
```

The return values of the subject are the same.

Is there any difference between the two? Even if it is subtle/not important, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 29):

`struct name_of_struct` refers unambiguously to a `struct`/`class` tagged `name_of_struct` whereas `name_of_struct` may be a variable or a function name.

For example, in POSIX, you have both `struct stat` and a function named `stat`. When you want to refer to the struct type, you need the `struct` keyword to disambiguate (+ plain C requires it always -- in plain C, regular identifiers live in a separate namespace from struct tags and struct tags don't leak into the regular identifier namespace like they do in C++ unless you explicitly drag them there with a typedef as in `typedef struct tag{ /*...*/ } tag;`).

[Example:](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lkG-yL)

```
struct  foo{ char x [256];};
void (*foo)(void);

int structsz(){ return sizeof(struct foo); } //returns 256
int ptrsz(){ return sizeof(foo); } //returns typically 8 or 4
```

If this seems confusing, it basically exists to maintain backwards compatibility with C.

Comment: One additional minor note, the `struct` and `class` keywords are interchangeable in this context.  `sizeof(struct foo)` and `sizeof(class foo)` would both work.  You don't see the latter very often though, since this mainly comes up in the context of interoperating with C code.

Comment: Furthermore `struct name_of_struct` i.e. an elaborated type specifier also declares `name_of_struct`. This doesn't make a difference in this particular case, since in order to use `sizeof`, `name_of_struct` must be defined, and therefore declared prior. But in another case, it can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

And, of course,

```
sizeof name_of_struct
```

is a valid expression only when name_of_struct is an object (not just a type); writing

```
sizeof(struct name_of_struct)
```

will not compile unless name_of_struct is already defined (complete type) to be a struct (or class).  But wait, there's more!  If both exist then

```
sizeof(struct name_of_struct)
```

will get you the size of the type, not the object, whereas both

```
sizeof(name_of_struct)
```

and

```
(sizeof name_of_struct)
```

will get you the size of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: the difference is c style struct notation versus C++ notation.

Comment: No, they are both C++. `sizeof(name_of_struct)` is only C++ i.e. not C, unless `name_of_struct` is also a `typedef`.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly